# How to reduce cyclomatic complexity this pipe Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular

How could I improve my code? Any idea?

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Images } from 'src/app/interfaces/images/images.model';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter',
  pure: false
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: Images[], filteringString: string, ...arg: string[]): Images[] {
    if (value.length === 0 || filteringString === '') {
      return value;
    }
    const resultArray = [];
    for (const item of value) {
      for (const spreadArgument of arg) {
        if (item[spreadArgument].toString().includes(filteringString)) {
          resultArray.push(item);
        }
      }
    }
    return resultArray;
  }
}
```

It is working fine but cyclomatic complexity is too high and very bad for digest cycle.
Thanks :)

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to post this question.

Comment: I can see a computational complexity improvement, but the cyclomatic complexity looks pretty reasonable to me